# WooCommerce trigger a function on order status complete

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to trigger a function when an order is completed. I am using this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', array($this, 
  'payment_complete' 
), 1);
```

and then this function:

```
public function payment_complete($order_id) { 
  $this->generate_order_file($order_id); 
}
```

This function is meant to generate an order file, but it's not being called at all. I previously tried getting it to add a message to the error log,

I am using the WooCommerce Order Status Control plugin, and orders are automatically changing to complete upon payment. Yet for some reason the woocommerce_order_status_completed action isn't triggering.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is using this action:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'your_function', 10, 1);
function your_function($order_id) {
}
```

Comment: Why is this the best way?

Comment: @upss1988 Because it reduces function calls. You only need to run this function on "completed" status. Regarding the other answer, there's no need to run the function on all status changes and filter out the ones that we don't need.

Answer (score 3):

**FUNCTION**

```
function payment_complete( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){
        if( $new_status == "completed" ) {
            $this->generate_order_file($order_id); 
        }
}
```

**HOOK**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', array( $this, 'payment_complete'), 99, 3 );
```

**NOTE**

Make sure that the hook is executed. Is yes, this will work.

Good luck.

Comment: You can only use  'payment_complete' as the second argument instead of array( $this, 'payment_complete') if you are using it as a function in function.php or generally anywhere that you are not using Class in WP

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, change with simple if condition

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'so_status_completed', 10, 3);
function so_status_completed($order_id)
{
if( get_post_meta( $order_id, 'download_link', true ) ){
    $note = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'download_link', true );
} else {
    $note = __("Status updated with no link.");
}

// The order note or you can change as your requirement 
if( isset($note) && ! empty($note) ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order Object
    $order->add_order_note( $note );  // Add the note
    $order->save(); // Save the order
}
}
```